# Trying to get a data field from our Firestore database but the integer is returned as null

Tags: asynchronous, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, widget

The method in my code is supposed to grab the timeout needed for questions for our survey mobile app. The method, however, only returns null even though we establish a document snapshot that should hold a copy of the data. We have a fallback hard coded in so that when the timeout is null it will return a default widget.

WE have tried several asyncs and awaits in the widget and the method it self and none of them seem to be able to make the widget wait for the timeout from the firestore document.

```dart
const fiveSeconds = Duration(seconds: 5);
Future<int> getTimeOutData() async{
  int toReturn;
  Firestore.instance.collection("config").getDocuments().then((DocumentSnapshot) async=>{
    Future.delayed(fiveSeconds, () async => toReturn = await DocumentSnapshot.documents[0]['timeout']),
    print( toReturn)
  });
  return toReturn;
}
```

```
Widget _buildListItem(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot doc) {
  return ListTile(
    title: Text(
      doc['question_text'].toString(),
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline,
    ),
    dense: true,
    trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 5.0),
    onTap: () async{
      timeout= await getTimeOutData();
      envelope = new Envelope(doc['complete'], doc.documentID, doc['user'],
          doc['question'], doc['answer_text'], doc['answer_type'], doc['time_stamp']);
       Navigator.push(
        context,
         MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) {
            return ViewAnswerController(envelope,  timeout);
          },
        ),
      );
    },
    selected: true,
  );
}
```

I expect 1 millisecond but the actual value is null on print within the method and on a later check in a different widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const fiveSeconds = Duration(seconds: 5);
Future<int> getTimeOutData() async{
  int toReturn;
  await Firestore.instance.collection("config").getDocuments().then((DocumentSnapshot) async=>{
    await Future.delayed(fiveSeconds, () async => toReturn = await DocumentSnapshot.documents[0]['timeout']),
    print( toReturn)
  });
  return toReturn;
}
```

Nevermind I just needed some more awaits because .then() is also a Future object.